# creating a function that loops through inputs to check if they are blank

Tags: jquery, forms, function

I'm trying to create a function that accepts a div id as an argument and then searches through that div, checking if all of the required text inputs are filled.

I can't change the HTML, I can only add JS to the page.

I'm unsure how I can target only the inputs that are required, and then check all of them to see that they are complete.

```
checkinputs = function(block){

$('block > :input').keyup(function() {
    var $emptyFields = $('block :input').filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value) === "";
    });

    if (!$emptyFields.length) {
        alert("form has been filled");
    }
    else {
    alert("form is still missing input");
    }
  });
};

$('body').on("click", "#step_3", function(e){ 
checkinputs('#ctl00_MainContentHolder_StoreAddressEditorBilling_addressDiv');
});
```

I have all of the code in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AebC6/1/

Comment: FYI, note that your "Phone" has a white '*' on white background - and IS a required based on the "id" ending...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checkinputs = function (block) {
    var notAllFilled = $(block).find('input').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) === "";
    });
    var alertText = notAllFilled ? "form is still missing input" : "form has been filled";
    alert(alertText);
}

$('body').on("click", "#step_3", function (e) {
    checkinputs('#ctl00_MainContentHolder_StoreAddressEditorBilling_addressDiv');
});
```

EDIT: Updated with a VERY verbose version.
Checks for hidden inputs and ignores those. Gives the good ones lime background and bad ones aqua, and shows those it IS validating with a pink parent background.

Also adjusts the "*" text depending on validity.

This is ENTIRELY dependent on the id ending of the elements in the blog.

You WILL need to clean this up for production!

```
checkinputs = function (block) {
    var validators = $(block).find("[id$='RequiredIndicator']").parent().parent('tr').find(':input:not(:hidden)');
    var notAllFilled = validators.filter(function () {
        var myInput = $(this); //.parent().parent('tr').find(':input');
        var filledVal = myInput.val();
        var isFilled = $.trim(filledVal).length;
        if (isFilled) {
            myInput.css('background-color', 'lime');
            $(this).parent('td').prev('td').find('span').text(' ');
        } else {
            myInput.css('background-color', 'aqua');
            $(this).parent('td').prev('td').find('span').text('*');
        }
        return isFilled;
    }).length;
    validators.parent().css('background-color', 'pink');
    var inputCount = validators.length;
    var alertText = notAllFilled == inputCount ? "form has been filled" : "form is still missing input";
    alert(alertText);
};

$('body').on("click", "#step_3", function (e) {
    checkinputs('#ctl00_MainContentHolder_StoreAddressEditorBilling_addressDiv');
});
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I updated my fiddle with your code. It is starting to work, however it still says that there are blank inputs even when they are all filled, and it does'nt seem to check only the required fields.  http://jsfiddle.net/AebC6/6/

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not using the `block` argument that you're passing in.

```
$('block > :input').keyup(function() { ... });
```

The above selector is looking for an element `<block>` and get any child `input` elements

Use the `block` as an argument as follows:

```
$(block).find(':input').keyup(function() { ... });

$(block).find(':input').filter(function() { ... });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EGCWq/

Comment: Assuming that block is an object of sorts, $(':input',block) will also work. It should work exactly the same.